# what to setup in SQL profiler to investigate SSAS Cube synchronization job hang?

Tags: ssas, cube, sql-server-profiler, msbi

I am using SSIS job to process the ssas DB(cube, dim, partition etc) in source server and XMLA script in the same SSIS package to synchronize the SSAS DB from source server to destination server. This SSIS job is deployed and get initiated daily on source server.

This was running fine since years, but recently SSAS DB Synchronization is getting hang and not stopping/completing even after 3-4 hours. Generally it takes 30 minutes to complete. then I need to kill the job and manually sync the SSAS DB using synchronization wizard at destination server.

any way to figure out the real problem? what events to setup in SQL profiler to catch this issue while ssas db sync? or any other way?Also SQL Profiler should be run against source server or destination server?

Please help/guide/suggest. Thanks